# JavaFx Audio stopped after seconds

Tags: javafx

i have a problem. I this code :

```
         URL thing = getClass().getResource(Song);
         Media audioFile = new Media( thing.toString() );
         MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(audioFile);
         m.setAutoPlay(true);
```

And if i run this code, my MP3 gegins to play, but stopp afer a few seconds! 
I dont want, that the audio file stopps.

---

Here is the code

```js
package javafxapplication1;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
/**
 *
 * @author rodey_000
 */
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Label Sample");
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(180);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Button button1 = new Button("Bild");
        button1.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
        button1.setTranslateX(-430);
        button1.setTranslateY(30);
        String T ="TroubleSeeker.mp3";
     

     
        
        
        Label label1 = new Label("Bild");
        label1.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", 30));
        label1.setTranslateY(0); 
        
        Label label5 = new Label("User");
        label5.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", 30));
        label5.setTranslateY(100);
        label5.setTranslateX(-300);
        
        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setPromptText("Enter BildName.png.");
        name.setPrefColumnCount(10);
        name.setText("testbild.png");
        name.getText();
        name.setTranslateX(-40);
        
        
        final TextField name2 = new TextField();
        name2.setPromptText("Enter Songname.mp3.");
        name2.setPrefColumnCount(10);
         name2.setText("TroubleSeeker.mp3");
        name2.getText();
        name2.setTranslateX(-270);
        name2.setTranslateY(55);
       
        
        final TextField name3 = new TextField();
        name3.setPromptText("Enter User");
        name3.setPrefColumnCount(10);
        name3.setText("Michael");
        name3.getText();
        
        name3.setTranslateX(-440);
        name3.setTranslateY(100);
        
        
        
        
        
        
         button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
             Stage secondaryStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
             Group root2 = new Group();
             Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
             String TextBild = name.getText();
             String TextAufBild = name3.getText();
             String Song = name2.getText();
             int lenght = name3.getLength();
             play(Song);
             
            
            
               
              
            
            
             
             Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(TextBild));
             double high = image.getHeight();
             double widht = image.getWidth();
             
                secondaryStage.setTitle("Label Sample");
                secondaryStage.setWidth(600);
                secondaryStage.setHeight(300);
        
                
            Label label3 = new Label();
             label3.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
             
             Label label4= new Label(TextAufBild);
             label4.setFont(new Font("", 50));
             label4.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
             label4.setTranslateY(50);
             
             if(lenght == 1){
             label4.setTranslateX(-340);
             }
             else if(lenght == 2){
             label4.setTranslateX(-350);
             }
             else if(lenght == 3){
             label4.setTranslateX(-360);
             }
             else if(lenght == 4){
             label4.setTranslateX(-370);
             }
             else if(lenght == 5){
             label4.setTranslateX(-380);
             }
             else if(lenght == 6){
             label4.setTranslateX(-390);
             }
             else if(lenght == 7){
             label4.setTranslateX(-400);
             }
             else if(lenght == 8){
             label4.setTranslateX(-410);
             }
             else if(lenght == 9){
             label4.setTranslateX(-420);
             }
             else if(lenght == 10){
             label4.setTranslateX(-430);
             }
             else if(lenght == 11){
             label4.setTranslateX(-440);
             }
              else if(lenght == 12){
             label4.setTranslateX(-450);
             }
              else if(lenght == 13){
             label4.setTranslateX(-460);
             }
              else if(lenght == 14){
             label4.setTranslateX(-470);
             }
              else if(lenght == 15){
             label4.setTranslateX(-480);
             }
             
             HBox hbox2 = new HBox();  
             hbox2.setSpacing(10);
              
             hbox2.getChildren().add((label3));
             hbox2.getChildren().add((label4));
            
             ((Group)scene2.getRoot()).getChildren().add(hbox2);
             
             secondaryStage.setTitle("Secondary Stage"); 
             secondaryStage.setScene(scene2);
             secondaryStage.show();
             
             
            
            }
        });
        
          
        
        Label label2 = new Label("Song");
        label2.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", 30));
        label2.setTranslateY(50);
        label2.setTranslateX(-58);
        label2.setTranslateZ(1);
        
        
        
       
        
        
      

        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.getChildren().add(label1);
        hbox.getChildren().add(label2);
        hbox.getChildren().add(name);
        hbox.getChildren().add((label5));
        hbox.getChildren().add(name2);
        hbox.getChildren().add(name3);
       
        hbox.getChildren().add(button1);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(hbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
     public void play(String Song){
         URL thing = getClass().getResource(Song);
             Media audioFile = new Media( thing.toString() );
             MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(audioFile);   
            m.play();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: How long is the audio file and when does it stop playing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to play through the whole sound file, you have to use a MediaView.

Here's a basic example where the file "test.mp3" is in the same directory as the class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.net.URL;

public class MusicPlayer extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 210);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Music Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        final URL resource = getClass().getResource("test.mp3");
        Media media = new Media(resource.toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }
}
```